# Export-Csv creates an empty file

Tags: powershell, export-csv

I want to export the result of my script to a new CSV file. Unfortunately the `Export-Csv` only creates an empty file. I think there is a problem with the `Write-Host` which can't be saved into a file?

Maybe there is an option to just save the output of the console to a txt/csv-file.

```
$Date = $((Get-Date).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd'))

$Evaluation = {
    $Users = Get-ADUser -Filter 'enabled -eq $true' -SearchBase $OU -Properties mailNickname

    Write-Host "Name;CAL Exchange"

    foreach ($User in $Users) {
        if ($User.mailNickName -eq $null) {
            $User.CALEX = "No"
        } else {
            $User.CALEX = "Yes"
        }
        Write-Host "$($User.Name);$($User.CALEX)"
    }
    Write-Host ""
    Write-Host "Count: $($Users.Count) Users"
}

$Evaluation_Department = {
    $OU = "OU=ofDepartment"
    & $Evaluation | Export-Csv -Path "C:\Support\$($Date)-Department.csv"
}
& $Evaluation_Department
```

I except this to be in the file:

```
Name;CAL Exchange
$($User.Name);$($User.CALEX)
[...]
$($User.Name);$($User.CALEX)

Count: $($Users.Count) Users
```

`& $Evaluation_Department` was just for testing purposes.

Comment: What exactly output you are expecting to see? One column `$User.Name`, and one `$User.CALEX`? And also, what is the purpose to store the code into the variable and execute it with `&`? Is there some logic that I am missing?

Comment: Write-Host is like 'print' - it sends the text to the powershell window. Try removing it.

Comment: I'm not so sure what output you're expecting here with your code, could you explain the expected output?

Comment: Trying to write a PS script in the same way you write another language isn't appropriate.What you're trying to do is very simple to do, but not in the way you;re doing it. As mentioned above, don;t use write-host - if you want to export to csv, pipe the array elements to it. Try this code to see what it does: Get-ADUser -Filter 'enabled -eq $true' -SearchBase $OU | export-csv -Path c:\temp\test.csv

Answer (score 1):

The desired file can be generated by a simplified version of your script:

```bsh
$Date = $((Get-Date).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd'))
$OU = "OU=ofDepartment"

$Users = Get-ADUser -Filter 'enabled -eq $true' -SearchBase $OU -Properties mailNickname
$Users | Select-Object Name,@{name="CAL Exchange";e={if($User.mailNickName) {return "Yes"} else {return "No"}}} | Export-CSV -Path "C:\temp\$($Date)-Department.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Of course it wouldn't have `Count: X Users` at the end, but I removed this on purpose - personally I'd not put this in `.csv` file. You can add this easily by using `Add-Content`.

---

**NOTE**: Be careful with data format while adding content manually to CSV file - otherwise it might become not readable by Excel for example. Usually, you'll have to remember about `"`

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for

```
$date = $((Get-Date).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd'))    
$OU = "OU=_Users,CN=..."

$Users = Get-ADUser -Filter 'enabled -eq $true' -SearchBase = $OU -Properties mailNickname

$Users | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name CALEX -Value $null -Force

foreach ($User in $Users)
{
    if ($User.mailNickName -eq $null)
    {
        $User.CALEX = "No"
    }
    else
    {
        $User.CALEX = "Yes"
    }
}    

$Users | Select-Object SamAccountName, CALEX | Export-CSV -Path "C:\Support\$($Date)-Department.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Force
```

Comment: Almost done, but `CALEX` will be `ADPropertyValueCollection` so you have to access its value (for example using calculated property)